# Comparing more than two versions of a file

Tags: comparison, compare, winmerge

I have several environments using configuration files. In order to merge those files, I would like to be able to compare them. However, comparing two files at a time when having five environments is quite tiresome.

Does anybody know of a tool which would provide a quick way to compare n files to a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Diff, Match and Patch (https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) supplied me with the tools I needed. I quickly implemented a Java comparer which compare each file to the one I choose as a reference. I still have to look at four comparison results, but I ask only once the comparison and all the results are on the same page, making it easier to locate exceptions.

I must clean the code a little but will try to share it if anybody is interested.

Comment: This is old and does not attract many views, but if you need my algorithm, it is available on Github: https://github.com/cyChop/tree-comparer

A colleague of mine even included a previous version inside one of the applications he was working on. I still have some cleaning to do, but it should work.